# Vertical align caption text on image

Tags: html, css

How would I vertically align text to the middle of a  caption that has a position of absolute. I want the text whether it be 1 line or 2 lines for it to be in the middle of the green block.

Here is a example:
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/7467/

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
    <div class="holder">
        <div class="background">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            <h4>I am some text that needs</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
    <div class="holder">
        <div class="background">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            <h4>I am some text that</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>   
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
    <div class="holder">
        <div class="background">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            <h4>I am some text that needs</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>    
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
    <div class="holder">
        <div class="background">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            <h4>I am some text that needs</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>    
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
    <div class="holder">
        <div class="background">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            <h4>I am some text that</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>    
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
    <div class="holder">
        <div class="background">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            <h4>I am some text that needs</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

.holder {
    position:relative;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.background {
    background: #000;
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
}

.text {
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

h4 {
    background: green;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    min-height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean to be aligned vertically as middle?

Comment: I know how to do this, I'm just waiting til I have a spare moment to code it for you.  Stand by...

Comment: Thanks I've got it to centre using table-cell and vertical-align middle but the only issue is now that when using table-cell the green box is not 100% of the width

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/7471/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### UPDATED

Like this ....

[FIDDLE v4](https://jsfiddle.net/incept0/DTcHh/7474/)

This version I believe may have it.

Changed the `<h4>` to a `<p>`

**Removed from `<p>`**

```
width: 100%;
display: table-cell;
```

**Added to `<p>`**

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
transform: translateY(25%);
```

**Changes to `<p>`**

`padding: 5px 10px;` *-TO-* `padding: 0px 10px;`

Comment: Hey Thanks for your solution, but im looking for something more like this https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/7471/. I just cannot seem to get the text to center because table-cell makes the element inline rather then block.

Comment: @jezuitazus sorry for the lag,  I am working with that code on my own server.  jsfiddle is cool and all, but it also kinda sucks.   the answer i posted will work, I just did a horrible job of explaining it.  I'll update the answer here in a minute to make more sense and provide an integrated version of your code.

Comment: @jezuitazus If my answer was the correct solution to your problem please click the check mark to the left of this answer.  Also if you found my answer helpful please click the up arrow as well.  Thanks  :)

Comment: Sorry I believe I may of confused you :( the green box positioning is suppose to be on the bottom but the text inside the box wont align to the middle vertically and horizontally at the same time.

Comment: @jezuitazus Updated with new fiddle.   Working on the green bar to show up still, but centered in black area

Comment: @jezuitazus OK, I think I got it this time.  Check new fiddle in answer.

Comment: Ok, I still think your slightly confused haha, Heres a fiddle of how it should look https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/7473/ BUT THE TEXT CENTERED HORIZONTALLY. The first box is how I want it to look that is correct but the 2-6 text is not long enough to go the entire width of the element. ive tried text-align: center; marign: auto;
nothing seems to want to center the text.

Comment: @jezuitazus Can you check the latest fiddle in my answer and tell me if that is how you wanted it ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `line-height` on `h4` style with value more than double of the `font-size`:

```
h4 {

    background: green;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    min-height: 50px; 
   line-height: 2.2em;

}
```

Checkout this [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/7469/)

Comment: Hi Thanks for your solution but some of the text wraps on to a second line in my design, I'd prefer a different method like 
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle; but It does not seem to work when using absolute positioning

Comment: In your situation, I prefer the `line-height` and adjust the value manually. i.e try and error, i.e try it 2.3 em, 2.4em and so on till you get the align needed.